# sport club booking systems database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, oracle11g

I am designing a database to book sporting ground in clubs which can be like badminton courts, table tennis and each sporting facility can be booked for 1 hr and some clubs can take booking for minimum of 2 hours and it varies. Each club does have more than 1 courts for the same game. The booking charges for clubs varies from day to day and within day it depend on time as well eg: sunday morning form 5 am to 9 am charges are 150 while from 9 am to 5 pm its 100 and 5 pm to 12 pm its 200. Monday morning charges could be morning 5 am to 9 am 200 and 9 am to 12 it could be 150 etc ...

I am designing a system so that while quering the DB I should be able to find the data in optimized time for following queries filter.

1. I should be able to change the schedule of game without any issue for example if a game is booked for 150 on a particular day like monday, I should be able to make changes so that I can increase charges.
2. at a particular time I should be able to know if any court is available for booking

I have designed following tables for it.

```
{
  create database test;
use test;
create table city(
    city_id bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
    city_name varchar(128) not null unique key,
    primary key(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table club(
    club_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    club_name varchar(512) not null,
    city_id bigint(20) not null ,
    city_name varchar(128) not null,
    address varchar(1024) not null,
    postal_code varchar(12) not null,
    description text,
    primary key(club_id),
    foreign key city_id references city(city_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table game(
    game_id int not null auto_increment,
    game_name varchar(64) not null,
    game_description text,
    primary key(game_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table club_game(
    club_game_id bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
    club_id bigint(20) not null,
    game_id int not null ,
    primary key(club_game_id),
    foreign key (club_id) references club(club_id),
    foreign key (game_id) references game(game_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table club_game_offer(
    club_game_offer_id bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
    club_id bigint(20) not null,
    game_id int,
    offer_in_percentage double not null,
    offer_start_date timestamp,
    offer_end_date timestamp,
    primary key(club_game_fee_id),
    foreign key (club_id) references club(club_id),
    foreign key (game_id) references game(game_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table club_game_schedule(
    club_game_schedule_id bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
    club_id bigint(20) not null,
    game_id int not null,
    start_time timestamp not null,
    end_time timestamp not null,
    fee double not null,
    day varchar(128),
    game_court_count int not null,
    primary key(club_game_schedule_id),
    foreign key (club_id) references club(club_id),
    foreign key (game_id) references game(game_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table booking(
    booking_id bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
    club_game_schedule_id bigint(20) not null,
    date_of_booking date not null,
    offer_id bigint(20) not null,
    amount_paid double not null,
    primary key(booking_id),
    foreign key (offer_id) references club_game_offer(club_game_offer_id),
    foreign key (club_game_schedule_id) references club_game_schedule(club_game_schedule_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
}
```

The problem in this design in that I have to make entry for each hour in club_game_schedule table. Apart from that to check the availability of the court for a game I have to check the no of entry in booking table for that slot and then decide depending on the value of game_court_count.

Can anyone suggest better design.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the relationships between clubs and games and schedules? Does every club-game intersection have only a single schedule? What defines a schedule? Why no schedule table? What is an offer?

Comment: cardinality  between club and game is 1-n. Every club-game intersection will have many schedule depending on the day and hour of the day. For an example badminton is played on monday from 5am to 11 am and charge for 1 hr booking is 10$ , from 11 am to 5 pm it is 8 $ and from 5 pm to 11 pm it is 12 $. On tuesday it can be diff. Schedule defines schedule of the game for a particular day like shcdule on weekends, weekdays and public holidays and it also define its fee structure on that day. I have captured it in club_game_schedule. Offer list down offers going on in the club for a game.

Comment: "cardinality between club and game is 1-n." So each game is played at only a single club, and each club offers many games? I would've expected that this is many-to-many.

Comment: my mistake , it is many to many only